# How should I bootstrap multivariate variables?

Tags: statistics, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I want to bootstrap observations with multivariate variables from a sample for performing multivariate statistics. Should I bootstrap observations in rows(each observation represented by a row) with all the variables as a whole, or bootstrap each variable to combine into an observation?

[image]

Comment: My vote is to keep rows intact, so all you're resampling is your sample -- that is, the individuals that are represented in your dataset.  I could be corrected here, but bootstrapping each variable independently would violate the non-independence of a multivariate dataset.

Comment: Those two approaches are statistically non-equivalent